# plugin custom auth-method in jetty

Tags: jetty, web.xml, jetty-9

I want to write my own custom authenticator. I will implement jetty Authenticator interface. My war should have my custom auth method. I want to know how we can plugin custom auth method

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>MyCustomAuth</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>        
</login-config>
```

So if you look i want to hook **MyCustomAuth** method instead of using jetty native auth-methods.

It will be great if i get some hints on writing custom authenticator .

Thanks in advance